# How to generate Spring Data Entities from existing Database

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have a quite big MySQL database already created with different schemas in it. The project I am working on uses Spring Data with Hibernate and I need to generate entities and mappings from the database without coding them by hand.

What tool can do this automatically? I'm working in Netbeans but would be willing to change IDE.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called reverse engineering. The Hibernate Tools project helps you with that: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/master/maven/docs/5-minute-tutorial.md

No need to switch your IDE, just add a plugin to your build, or if you want to reverse engineer only once, then you just check-in the code and remove the plugin after the initial reverse engineering.